# Indent the word "Proof" in environment proof of amsthm

Tags: indentation, amsthm

I'm working with the `amsthm` package, especially using the `proof` environment. I would like just the word "Proof" to be indented (and to keep the `QED` symbol). Can we do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\hskip\labelsep}{\hskip5\labelsep}{}{}  %% change 5 here as you wish

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This is the proof of the lemma This is the proof of the lemma This is the proof of the lemma This is the proof of the lemma This is the proof of the lemma
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You have to load `xpatch` package (by adding `\usepackage{xpatch}` in the preamble) and then add the following to your preamble:

```
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\hskip\labelsep}{\hskip5\labelsep}{}{}
```

If you don't have `xpatch` installed, then add the following to your preamble (after `\usepackage{amsthm}`)

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \normalfont
  \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@ \trivlist
  \item[\hskip5\labelsep\itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \qed\endtrivlist
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: The result is exactely what I wanted, but I'm working with `\documentclass[11pt]{article}`

Comment: I dont't know, but he doesn't understand the xpatch package you used. Do we have to load it somewhere ?

Comment: Thank you. But I've never loaded a package...
Could you explain me what to do ?
I've downloaded the file at https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch

Comment: That's perfect, even if I don't understand it ;-)

Comment: @Zweig42 I copied the definition of `proof` from `amsthm.sty`, enclosed it between `\makratletter` and `\makeatother` and added `re` in `\renewenvironment` and `5` in `5\labelsep`. That's all :)

Comment: @HarishKumar -- an even easier mod is to adapt the definition of proof from `amsproc.cls` where it is already indented.  that inserts the line `\itemindent\normalparindent` between `\trivlist` and `\item`, and leaves `\hskip\labelsep` unchanged.  this also requires in the preamble, before redefining `proof`, insertion of a line `\normalparindent\parindent`.  (ams document classes avoid this problem by establishing `\normalparindent` in the class file.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton If you add this as an answer, I'd be glad to upvote it.  Just let me know if you do it.

Comment: @Alex -- Answer added.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to accomplish this request is to adapt the definition of `proof` from `amsproc.cls` where it is already indented.

That definition inserts the line `\itemindent\normalparindent` between `\trivlist` and `\item`, and leaves `\hskip\labelsep` unchanged.

This also requires in the preamble, before redefining `proof`, insertion of a line `\normalparindent\parindent`.

(AMS document classes avoid this problem by establishing `\normalparindent` in the class file.)