# Left align the "Proof." at the beginning of the proof environment containing a Tikz picture

Tags: align, proof-package

Here is some code that should run,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{Identity 1.} \textit{For $n \geq 2$,}
\[
{\color{blue} {n \choose 2}} + {\color{red} {{n+1} \choose 2} } \ = \ n^2.
\]

\begin{proof} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]  
\foreach \x in {0,...,8} {%
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\x} {%
        \filldraw[red]  (0.5*\x,0.5*\y) circle (2pt);
    }%
}%

\foreach \x in {0,...,7} {%
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\x} {%
        \filldraw[blue]  (3.5-0.5*\x,4-0.5*\y) circle (2pt);
    }%
}%   

\draw[|-|,red] (0,-0.5)  -- (4,-0.5) node[midway,below] {$n$};
\draw[|-|,red] (4.5,0)  -- (4.5,4) node[midway,right] {$n$};

\draw[|-|,blue] (0,4.5)  -- (3.5,4.5) node[midway,above] {$n-1$};
\draw[|-|,blue] (-0.5,0.5)  -- (-0.5,4) node[midway,left] {$n-1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

and here is what it produces.

[image]

As you can see, the "Proof." at the beginning is not left aligned, which is bothering me. How can I fix that?

Comment: the `center` command will shift everything to center-- so remove that --now you have left alignment--to give space add `hspace` of 2cm--you can experiment --see the answer below

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because too specific.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \noindent\textbf{Identity 1.} \textit{For $n \geq 2$,}
    \[
    {\color{blue} {n \choose 2}} + {\color{red} {{n+1} \choose 2} } \ = \ n^2.
    \]
    
    \begin{proof} \hspace{2cm}
%       \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]  
            \foreach \x in {0,...,8} {%
                \foreach \y in {0,...,\x} {%
                    \filldraw[red]  (0.5*\x,0.5*\y) circle (2pt);
                }%
            }%
            
            \foreach \x in {0,...,7} {%
                \foreach \y in {0,...,\x} {%
                    \filldraw[blue]  (3.5-0.5*\x,4-0.5*\y) circle (2pt);
                }%
            }%   
            
            \draw[|-|,red] (0,-0.5)  -- (4,-0.5) node[midway,below] {$n$};
            \draw[|-|,red] (4.5,0)  -- (4.5,4) node[midway,right] {$n$};
            
            \draw[|-|,blue] (0,4.5)  -- (3.5,4.5) node[midway,above] {$n-1$};
            \draw[|-|,blue] (-0.5,0.5)  -- (-0.5,4) node[midway,left] {$n-1$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
%       \end{center}
    \end{proof}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `\hfill` instead of `center` environment and observe that `~\par` used as *proof* text. Also remove that `[baseline=..]`, for the QED mark to appear after the tikzpicture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{Identity 1.} \textit{For $n \geq 2$,}
\[
{\color{blue} {n \choose 2}} + {\color{red} {{n+1} \choose 2} } \ = \ n^2.
\]

\begin{proof}~\par    
\hfill                  % <---
\begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]  % <---
\foreach \x in {0,...,8} {%
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\x} {%
        \filldraw[red]  (0.5*\x,0.5*\y) circle (2pt);
    }%
}%
\foreach \x in {0,...,7} {%
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\x} {%
        \filldraw[blue]  (3.5-0.5*\x,4-0.5*\y) circle (2pt);
    }%
}%
\draw[|-|,red] (0,-0.5)  -- (4,-0.5) node[midway,below] {$n$};
\draw[|-|,red] (4.5,0)  -- (4.5,4) node[midway,right] {$n$};
\draw[|-|,blue] (0,4.5)  -- (3.5,4.5) node[midway,above] {$n-1$};
\draw[|-|,blue] (-0.5,0.5)  -- (-0.5,4) node[midway,left] {$n-1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill             % <---
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thinked below "For" the word "Proof" :-(. Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Using [xpatch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235735/indent-the-word-proof-in-environment-proof-of-amsthm) and using correctly the package `amsthm`, putting `\newtheorem` you will have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newtheorem{id}{Identity}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\hskip\labelsep}{\hskip-2\labelsep}{}{} %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235735/indent-the-word-proof-in-environment-proof-of-amsthm
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{id} 
For $n \geq 2$,
\[
{\color{blue} {n \choose 2}} + {\color{red} {{n+1} \choose 2} } \ = \ n^2.
\]

\begin{proof} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]  
\foreach \x in {0,...,8} {%
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\x} {%
        \filldraw[red]  (0.5*\x,0.5*\y) circle (2pt);
    }%
}%

\foreach \x in {0,...,7} {%
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\x} {%
        \filldraw[blue]  (3.5-0.5*\x,4-0.5*\y) circle (2pt);
    }%
}%   

\draw[|-|,red] (0,-0.5)  -- (4,-0.5) node[midway,below] {$n$};
\draw[|-|,red] (4.5,0)  -- (4.5,4) node[midway,right] {$n$};

\draw[|-|,blue] (0,4.5)  -- (3.5,4.5) node[midway,above] {$n-1$};
\draw[|-|,blue] (-0.5,0.5)  -- (-0.5,4) node[midway,left] {$n-1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{proof}
\end{id} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can shift left **Proof** again decrease the negative value `\hskip-2`.