# Indent the word 'Proof' without using xpatch?

Tags: environments, indentation, amsthm

I can't figure out how to work around this problem. I need to indent the word 'Proof' in the proof environment of amsthm without using the xpatch (xpatch is described in here [Indent the word “Proof” in environment proof of amsthm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235735/indent-the-word-proof-in-environment-proof-of-amsthm)).

I want to avoid using any patches because they might stop working in the future. I want to do this using amsthm package only.

This is the minimum working code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\newtheoremstyle{sltheorem}
{2pt}                % Space above
{-2pt}                % Space below
{\it}        % Theorem body font % (default is "\upshape")
{17pt}                % Indent amount
{\scshape}       % Theorem head font % (default is \mdseries)
{.}               % Punctuation after theorem head % default: no punctuation
{ }               % Space after theorem head
{Theorem \thetheorem}                % Theorem head spec
\theoremstyle{sltheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{one}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[2]
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum[2]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @KersouMan thanks for the edit.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE ... Is `\renewcommand` suits for you?

Comment: @MadyYuvi yes, it does.

Comment: Using `\renewcommand` is not really better than patching: if the definition of `\proof` changes, the patch may cease to work (and you may be warned of the failure if you use something like `\ddt` in the trailing argument (any undefined command would do), but the `\renewcommand` will pass unnoticed and give an altogether different result.

Comment: @PeppaPig `egreg` is one of the Boss in `TeX/LaTeX`, please follow as he suggested...

Comment: The answer to the question given in the link provides a solution that do not use `xpstch`

Comment: @egreg so what do you suggest? Is it possible to do something similar that I have done for the theorem? It didn't have any indent of the first line but it has an argument that can be changed. Maybe the same is possible with proof environment?

Comment: @PeppaPig No, `proof` is not defined in terms of `\newtheoremstyle`.

Comment: (they are in `ntheorem` but egreg is not a fan of `ntheorem`)

Comment: Ok, I decided to remove indent of theorem and proof. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you could do `\renewcommand\proofname{\hspace*{17pt}Proof}` (assuming that you don't use  \proofname in other places).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks. If I decide to add the indent in the future I will keep that in mind.